# Why IsoDateTimeConverter is not used to serialize Dictionary<DateTime, int>

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

The result of a webAPI method that return a Dictionary is not serialized with the format defined in IsoDateTimeConverter

This is my configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    //Web API configuration and services
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'"
        });
    }
}
```

Here a sample of webAPI method

```
[Route("GetPlanning")]
[HttpPost]
public Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<int>> GetPlanning()
{
    Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<int>> planning = new Dictionary<DateTime,IEnumerable<int>>();
    planning.Add(DateTime.UtcNow, new List<int>(){0,1,2});
    return planning;
}
```

In client side the result is an object with a property that is a date without the millisecond.

If i return a array : `return planning.ToArray();` the result is an array of object key value with a date with millisecond.

So why the format is apllied on a date in a array and not in a dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `IsoDateTimeConverter` is not used for dictionary keys is that Json.NET does not serialize the keys - it merely converts them to strings.  From the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#Dictionarys):

> When serializing a dictionary, the keys of the dictionary are converted to strings and used as the JSON object property names. The string written for a key can be customized by either overriding ToString() for the key type or by implementing a TypeConverter. A TypeConverter will also support converting a custom string back again when deserializing a dictionary.

Thus converters, including `IsoDateTimeConverter`, are not used when converting dictionary keys to JSON.

That being said, `IsoDateTimeConverter` is no longer necessary. From [Serializing Dates in JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm)

> From Json.NET 4.5 and onward dates are written using the ISO 8601 format by default, and using this converter is unnecessary.

The same date formatting can be obtained by setting [JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateFormatString.htm):

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'";
```

But how does this affect dictionary key conversion to JSON?  As it turns out, Json.NET *does* respect this setting when converting a `DateTime` to a `string` as a dictionary key, as shown in the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L1115).  Thus:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;

Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<int>> planning = new Dictionary<DateTime, IEnumerable<int>>();
planning.Add(DateTime.UtcNow, new List<int>() { 0, 1, 2 });
var root = new { today = time, planning = planning };

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
    DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff'Z'",
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Produces the required output with consistent formatting for a `DateTime` value used as a dictionary keys and used as a property:

> ```
> {
>   "today": "2016-09-09T03:54:51.704Z",
>   "planning": {
>     "2016-09-09T03:54:51.704Z": [
>       0,
>       1,
>       2
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```